# non-expiring google calendar api channel java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, channel

How to make google calendar Channel doesn't expire? In the documentation it's said "If a channel has an expiration time", then it's mean it can have no expiration time. But every time I made a channel it always gave me expiration time of one week by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the docs are still ambiguous on this point. The [current doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#renewing-notification-channels) says:

> A notification channel can have an expiration time, with a value determined either by your request or by any Google Calendar API internal limits or defaults (the more restrictive value is used)

It seems that what actually is happening is that every notification channel has an expiration time, so creating one that doesn't isn't supported by the API.

In other words, you'd have to implement that yourself by refreshing the channel before it expires

Comment: PS The default expiration time seems to still be 1 week (at least with the Node client)